# Adding events to Davical server using Http request and DDay.iCal

Tags: httprequest, put, http-status-code-405, caldav

I am trying to add an event from my local database to the Davical server (in fact, this should apply to any CalDav server, as long as it is compliant with the CalDav protocol)...

From what I could read [here](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/), I can send a PUT request to add events contained in a VCALENDAR collection... So here is what I try to do:

```
     try {
        // Create the HttpWebRequest object
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://my_caldav_srv/davical.php/user/mycalendar");

        // Add the network credentials to the request
        Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usr, pwd);

        // Specify the method
        Request.Method = "PUT";    

        // some headers - I MAY BE MISSING THINGS HERE???
        Request.Headers.Add("Overwrite", "T");

        // set the body of the request...
        Request.ContentLength = bodyStr.Length;
        Stream reqStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the string to the destination as a text file.
        reqStream.Write( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body), 0, body.Length);

        // Set the content type header.
        Request.ContentType = contentType.Trim();

        // Send the method request and get the response from the server.
        Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Caught error: " + e.Message, e);
      }
```

The body I send is actually an emtpy calendar:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
  VERSION:2.0
  CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
  METHOD:PUBLISH
  PRODID:-//davical.org//NONSGML AWL Calendar//EN 
  X-WR-CALNAME:My Calendar
END:VCALENDAR
```

For a reason I cannot understand, the call with "PUT" returns an error (405) Method Not Allowed. The PUSH returns (500) Internal Server Error, but looking at the debug details, the reason is the same as for the PUT case...

In debugging on the server side, I found out that the reason is that in *caldav-PUT-vcalendar.php*, the following clause is violated:

```
$c->readonly_webdav_collections
```

Well, first, let me mention that with the SAME credentials entered in Lightning, I am able to add/remove events and, on the admin interface, I actually made sure to grant ALL rights to the user. So I'd be surprised it is due to that...

Any help would be most appreciated !
Kind regards,
Nik

Comment: Note that the iCalendar must not be indented in the way you show it above. All lines must start at column 0 (otherwise they get folded into one line by iCalendar parsers).

Comment: The Overwrite header is not for PUT, you can remove that. Instead use If-Match: 'ETag' and If-None-Match: * to protect against races.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it....

The reason is that one must put the event to some EVENT adress....

I.e. the "url" is not the collection's address, but the EVENT's address...

So the same code using the following address works:

```
string url="http://my_server/caldav.php/username/calendarpath/_my_event_id.ics";
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to insert / delete multiple events at once ???

Comment: There is no RFC'ed standard way of adding multiple items at once to a DAV server, but some (e.g. CalendarServer, iCloud) support this bulk upload extension: https://svn.calendarserver.org/repository/calendarserver/CalendarServer/trunk/doc/Extensions/calendarserver-bulk-change.txt