# iCloud vcalendar multiple events

Tags: python, caldav

I am trying to insert multiple events at once to an iCloud calendar. If I use this vcalendar, everything works just fine:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:12345678
DTSTART:20150213T170000Z
DTEND:20150213T180000Z
DTSTAMP:20150210T182145Z
SUMMARY:This is an event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

However, if I double the amount of events, like this, I get an error "unforbidden".

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:12345678
DTSTART:20150213T170000Z
DTEND:20150213T180000Z
DTSTAMP:20150210T182145Z
SUMMARY:This is an event
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:12345678
DTSTART:20150214T170000Z
DTEND:20150214T180000Z
DTSTAMP:20150210T182145Z
SUMMARY:This is an event or is it
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am sending the PUT request to (of course I am authenticated, also because the first request is successful):
https://p01-caldav.icloud.com:443/xxxxxxxx/calendars/work/xxxxxxx.ics

The specific error is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<error 
    xmlns='DAV:'>
    <valid-calendar-object-resource 
        xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'/>
    </error>
```

Any thoughts on why this happens, and more importantly: how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe useful: this problem might not be limited to iCloud alone. https://code.google.com/p/google-caldav-issues/issues/detail?id=45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to this question: [Adding events to Davical server using Http request and DDay.iCal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27609122/2203005).

The iCloud calendar is a CalDAV server. In CalDAV
([RFC 4791 Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-4.1))
each event/todo in a calendar is represented by a different HTTP resource and
hence needs to have a different URL.

You are trying to PUT multiple events into one resource, which is why the
'[valid-calendar-object-resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-5.3.2.1)' precondition is raised (not a valid CalDAV
resource because it contains multiple VEVENTs sections which are not part of a recurrence set).

There is no RFC'ed standard way of adding multiple items at once to a DAV
server, but some (including Apple CalendarServer and iCloud) support this bulk upload draft:
[Calendar Server Bulk Change Requests for *DAV Protocols](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/master/doc/Extensions/calendarserver-bulk-change.txt).

Essentially, in your case, instead of doing a PUT to /xx/calendars/work/abc.ics, try a POST to /xx/calendars/work/.
The server will then create the individual calendar subresources for you.

P.S.: And there is an extra bug in your request. You use the same UID (12345678) for multiple events (which are not part of a recurrence set). You need to assign unique UIDs.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing this up for me. It works! Regarding the UID: I know, forgot to change that after copy pasting ;).

Comment: This question and answer saved my time. I would like to know is there any limit in number of events in one request?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/master/doc/Extensions/calendarserver-bulk-change.txt#L775